# Outlook Scheduling Assistant

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

When using the scheduling assistant within Outlook to view free/busy time information for attendees. The chair person of the meeting will have meeting details displayed up to a certain date/time in the future, afterwards all entries are just blocks of time with no details. Users can continue to see other peoples details but not their own. What setting needs to be tweaked to allow that caching of data to be viewable? All users are O365 users running Outlook 2016 with cached exchange mode turned on with setting to keep all data offline.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean users cannot see their own free/busy information when opening a meeting?

Free/busy information is available no matter you are in cached Exchange mode or Online mode.

Are there any errors? Does Outlook show slashes?

We can clear the offline cache. This is located under Tools > Internet Options > General. In the "Temporary Internet Files" section, choose the "Delete files" button.

Besides, we can also run /cleanfreebusy command switch to restore Free/Busy data. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /cleanfreebusy and then press Enter.